# Comment dit-on « une vue de dessus » ?

Tags: expressions, demande-de-mot

Je voudrais exprimer « une vue de dessus » comme lorsque l'on regarde une carte.

Une vue plongée ou une vue aérienne?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lorsque l'on parle d'une vue "plongée", on fait plutôt référence à un axe de représentation pour une photographie, située au dessus d'un objet :

[image: Vue plongée]

Ce n'est pas approprié pour une carte. Si, en revanche, on parle d'une carte comme Google Maps, on parlera effectivement d'une vue aérienne, et plus précisément d'une vue **satellite** (si c'est justement la cartographie satellite). En réalité, la précision du terme dépend du moyen mis en œuvre pour effectuer la cartographie.

Source de l'image: [(image uniquement disponible en cache)](http://monsieurcaux.blogspot.fr/2011/10/angles-de-vue.html)

Comment: Merci et belle image.

Comment: J'ai d'ailleurs ajouté la source de l'image - même si le lien n'a plus l'air fonctionnel - trouvée en cache depuis google. :-)